# Successor of ArrayList in Windows 8 Metro Apps C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to use a row and column removing method in my array. Therefore I wanted to convert my array to `ArrayList` to use the `RemoveAt(int index)` method, but in Windows 8 Apps using .NET 4.5 there is no `ArrayList`. Could you give me a suggestion how to cast my simple `int[,]` array to another type, which has a row and column removing method?

Comment: Is there something wrong with List? I see no real advantage to using ArrayList in the first place.

Comment: @Yuck alive and well in .NET 4.5, but not in the WinRT subset of the framework: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/15/winrt-and-net-in-windows-8.aspx (see the paragraph just above the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a list of lists:

```
List<List<int>> array = new List<List<int>>();
```

And initialize it as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < orig_array.Length, i++)
{
    array.Add(new List<int>(orig_array[i]));
}
```

Using this approach, `array.RemoveAt(row)` would remove an entire row, whereas `array[row].RemoveAt(col)` would remove an element.

EDIT: As phoog indicated, the above initialization would need to be modified for an array declared as int[,], as follows:

```
for (int row = 0; row < orig_array.GetLength(0), row++)
{
    array.Add(new List<int>());
    for (int col = 0; col < orig_array.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        array[row].Add(orig_array[row, col]);
    }
}
```

The advantage to using a jagged array (as opposed to a rectangular array) in this case is being able to access entire rows, without the need to explicitly loop through the values.

Comment: this would work if the source is an `int[][]`, but not if it is an `int[,]` as indicated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList and  all non-generic collections for been removed from WinRT. This link [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_ArrayList_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart) will help you with replacing the the arraylist.